# Can the Compute Module 3 support 240fps from the Pi Camera v2?

Tags: camera, raspicam, compute-module-3

The [Compute Module 3](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/computemodule/RPI-CM-DATASHEET-V1_0.pdf) supports CAM1 with 4x Lane CSI MIPI as does the official doc for the [Sony IMX219 camera module](http://www.sony-semicon.co.jp/products_en/new_pro/april_2014/imx219_e.html). It has been explained in [many places](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=145815) that the reason the standard Raspberry Pi single board computers (v1, 2, 3 and Zero) don't support the full capabilities of the camera module are because they only support 2x CSI.

Does this mean that the Compute Module 3 can support the full high-speed capabilities of the IMX219 camera module such as 1280x720@180fps or 960x540@240fps? If so will the [picamera camera modes](http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.12/fov.html) be updated to support this?

Comment: Only [one place](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=977704#p977704) that I can find in that thread and the firmware developer also states that overclocking (of the GPU) is required to get to 120fps at 720p. That suggests to me the GPU is another limiting factor (unsurprising given it's where the majority of camera processing occurs) which would in turn suggest you won't get much more than 120fps even with 4 lanes on the CSI connector

Comment: IIRC __only one__ of the pair of camera connections on the CM/CM3/CM3Lite is a four-lane CSI {CAM1}, the other {CAM0} is only a two-lane one.